# two arrays.if one of the first array object value is true then second array some objects to be displayed if it is false another objects

Tags: angular

First array data:

```
[
  { FirstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", Value: 46 },
  { FirstName: "Jack", lastName: "Smith", Value: 53 },
  { FirstName: "James", lastName: "Bhal", Value: true }
]
```

Second array
proms:

```
[
  { Label: "Ram", Key: "ram", Value: 46 },
  { Label: "Rom", Key: "rom", Value: 46 },
  { Label: "Mouse", Key: "mouse", Value: 46 }
]
```

How to display two objects in second array if third object value in first array is false and display all objects in second array if third object in first array value is true in angular 6 html. Try using `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`

Comment: Did you try to write some code before putting it on SO ?

Comment: What is the output array?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In ts,

```
firstArray = [
    { FirstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", Value: 46 },
    { FirstName: "Jack", lastName: "Smith", Value: 53 },
    { FirstName: "James", lastName: "Bhal", Value: false }
  ]

  secondArray = [
    { Label: "Ram", Key: "ram", Value: 46 },
    { Label: "Rom", Key: "rom", Value: 46 },
    { Label: "Mouse", Key: "mouse", Value: 46 }
  ]
```

In html,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of secondArray;let i = index">
<div *ngIf="firstArray[2]?.Value === true || (firstArray[2]?.Value === false && i < 2)">{{ item | json }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **hugomac** works but it can be more reusable by removing some hardcoded values and unnecessary checking of `boolean` values by doing something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data2;let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="(data1[data1.length-1]?.Value) || ( !data1[data1.length-1]?.Value && i < (data1.length-1)) ">
    {{ item | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qs8va7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)